# Why don't consumer laptops come with swipe fingerprint sensors anymore?

Tags: laptop, fingerprint

During the era of Windows Vista and 7, just about every laptop sold to consumers where I live, from lower-end "multimedia" home PCs to higher-end machines, would have a swipe fingerprint sensor, where the user could swipe their finger to log on. Every single computer I purchased during that time had a fingerprint sensor, from the cheap $300 Pentium laptop to the more expensive machines (e.g. my VAIO Z series valued at around $2,000 at the time).

However, I've noticed that most consumer laptops sold these days no longer have the sensor, not even high-end machines. The last time I visited a computer store, there was only one model that had a fingerprint sensor, and that wasn't a "swipe" sensor (it was a "tap and hold" sensor like the one found on smartphones like my Nexus 6P). From what I can tell, it was right around when manufacturers gravitated toward smaller form factors, right around the Windows 8 era, when this trend stopped.

Why don't consumer laptops feature the swipe fingerprint sensor anymore, which used to be such a common feature earlier, with just about every laptop (other than small netbooks) featuring it?

And if the concern was that swipe sensors aren't secure enough, why isn't the smartphone-like "tap and hold" sensor more common?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows Vista required third-party support for authentication with a fingerprint.  When Windows 8 was released this changed, however with that capability, came specific hardware requirements to support that functionality.  Fingerprint sensors have improved in the last decade a great deal.  We can't really answer the reason those sensors don't support swiping (the reason hardware manufacturers don't select different sensors cannot be answered by the community.  As for the reason the form factor got smaller, that reason for that decision, would also be out of scope.

Comment: @Ramhound This isn't a question about why the manufacturers opted for a specific type of sensor. This is a question asking why manufacturers removed the sensor entirely in droves (it happens that the sensors they were using were all of the "swipe" variety). If the concern is that swipe sensors weren't secure, then this also asks why manufacturers opted not to put in a newer type of sensor. Additionally, on every fingerprint-equipped PC I had, the manufacturer had preinstalled tools for fingerprint authentication, and when I upgraded one to Windows 8, its built-in support worked just fine.

Comment: It would be nice if an insider from a laptop manufacturer answered this question.

Comment: That is unlikely to happen, at least it hasn’t happened, to date.  Why the manufacturers did something isn’t something we can even answer.  Some finger print scanners were compatible with the built-in support some were not.  Windows Hello also changed the requirements again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe people just didn't like the idea of giving their fingerprints to MS or Google or Apple (to be sold or shared with... ?).

And a smaller form factor means less room for scanners (that apparently were in low demand anyway). So they save space, complexity, and money by omitting them.

And I'm not sure they were ever working accurately anyway. The older "swipe" sensors needed to scan a finger at the same speed consistently & repeatedly. Seemed like they would never work, or any finger (or toe, or sausage) would unlock everything.

<sub>[I'm not sure this is really fully answerable here. I've listed reasons why they would be unwanted, but the definitive answer has to come from manufacturers.]</sub>

Comment: But back in those days, biometric data was stored on the PC itself, not on a cloud service. The push to remove fingerprint sensors happened before the massive privacy issues came to light.

Comment: I'm not sure about that detail, but if true it just reinforces my point about not wanting to hand over even more personal data *today*